# Stata: rename all variables which do not begin with x

Tags: rename, stata

I would like to add a prefix or suffix to all variables which do not begin with x:

```
clear
input xa xb c d
1 1 1 1
end
```

I thought something like this: `rename (!x)* y*` which should give this result: `xa xb yc yd`. 
Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not ideal in my mind, but off the top of my head, perhaps something like `renpfix` might be of use to you:

```
. clear
. input xa xb c d
            xa         xb          c          d
  1. 1 1 1 1
  2. end
. list

     +-----------------+
     | xa   xb   c   d |
     |-----------------|
  1. |  1    1   1   1 |
     +-----------------+

. renpfix "" y
. renpfix yx x
. list

     +-------------------+
     | xa   xb   yc   yd |
     |-------------------|
  1. |  1    1    1    1 |
     +-------------------+
```

Here, I've first added a prefix to all the variables, thus resulting in your first two variables having a prefix of `yx`; then I've replaced the `yx` prefix to get back to `x` for the first two variables.

#### Update

Another option is to use `ds` or `findname` (install using `search findname`) and using the `not` argument to negate the matched variables

```
. clear
. input xa xb c d
            xa         xb          c          d
  1. 1 1 1 1
  2. end
. list

     +-----------------+
     | xa   xb   c   d |
     |-----------------|
  1. |  1    1   1   1 |
     +-----------------+

. ds x*, not
c  d

. foreach v in `r(varlist)' {
  2. rename `v' y`v'
  3. }
. list

     +-------------------+
     | xa   xb   yc   yd |
     |-------------------|
  1. |  1    1    1    1 |
     +-------------------+
```

`ds` and `findname` store their results in `` `r(varlist)' ``, so you can use `foreach` after identifying the relevant variables.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I like the first one. It is simple and clever.

Answer (score 2):

The `foreach` loop can be avoided

```
. rename (`r(varlist)') (y=)
```

Comment: I assume this is to be run right after `ds x*, not`, right? But I keep getting an `invalid name r(198)` error. Any ideas? (I'm using Stata 11, by the way.)

Comment: This use of `rename` is restricted to Stata 12.

Comment: Aah... Tough luck for me then. The closest I came after your last comment was to use `renvars (\`r(varlist)'), prefix(y)` instead of my loop. Same Nick Cox credited in the help file?

Comment: `renvars` is partly my work. Also `ds` and `findname`. `renvars` (like `findname`) has to be installed first.